# vba for Linking the Listboxes in userform and accessing through button

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an userform with two Listboxes having Multiple option.

- The Listbox1, is populated with the Location 1 of column L of sheet Result.
- The Listbox2, is populated with the Location 2 of column M of sheet Result.

I have an Button designed as "GO!!"

Right now, I have a code, that works in such a way that, you click on the Listbox 1 (eg: Germany is Location1 , it filters for location ) 
Similarly, If you chose Listbox2 (eg.USA in location 2, it filters for location)

I would like to have a code, such a way that the two listboxes should be interlinked and accessed through button.

For Eg. If I click "USA" from Listbox1. "Germany" from Listbox2, I Click "GO", It should show me the results of USA;with Germany in my sheet2.

Also,If I am not selecting the Listbox2, then it should display the result only for listbox1 and viceversa.

Here is the code, I am using for listbox1. 
I change the Listbox name for second listbox and the column number with the same code.

```
Private Sub DoFilter1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strCriteria() As String, i As Integer, arrIdx As Integer
    ReDim Preserve strCriteria(0 To arrIdx)

    arrIdx = 0
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            ReDim Preserve strCriteria(0 To arrIdx)
            strCriteria(arrIdx) = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
            arrIdx = arrIdx + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Set ws = Sheets("Result")
    If arrIdx = 0 Then
        ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    Else
        ws.Range("A:P").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Array(strCriteria), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Could some one suggest me , how I could interlink them and access through buttons. Any lead would be helpful.

This is how my userform looks like. I would like to select the checkbox from the list and then click Ok to show the result. Also, I should be able to select more than one option in checkboxes.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code, This might be helpful. Thanks

```
        With ListBox1
            For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(x) Then
                    temp = temp & Chr(10) & .List(x)
                End If
            Next
        End With

        With ListBox2
            For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(x) Then
                    temp = temp & Chr(10) & .List(x)
                End If
            Next
        End With

        MsgBox temp & " is selected"
```

Comment: Yes inside the button, instead of the Msgbox you can enter that in the textbox or sheet reference any where you want to.

Comment: Chec this code

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
            With ListBox1
                For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    If .Selected(x) Then
                        temp = temp & Chr(10) & .List(x)
                    End If
                Next
            End With
            With ListBox2
                For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    If .Selected(x) Then
                        temp = temp & Chr(10) & .List(x)
                    End If
                Next
            End With
            MsgBox temp & " is selected"
End Sub

Comment: ya, I tried this. I have an problem, If I am delesting "USA" in listbox 1, I still want to have the result checked in Listbox2.

Comment: How will I do this ?

Comment: Also, In somecase, the selection I make are not available and they are blank, Is it possible I could have a msgbox that says, no results found

Comment: use else statement for the "statement", for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149794/discussion-between-jenny-and-nishit-dey).